# Weird behaviour of 'sed' utility

Tags: windows, command-line, sed

I'm using *sed* on Windows by the GnuWin32 port. I have a text file **input.txt** with this contents

```
ab
```

I tried these combined commands to separate the `a` character into a new line and then to delete the line containing this `a` character, as I thought the commands ran in one by one after each other

```
sed "s/a/\na\n/ ; /a/d" "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

However, I just got a blank **output.txt** file. If I split this into two different commands

```
sed "s/a/\na\n/" "input.txt" > "output1.txt"
sed "/a/d" "output1.txt" > "output2.txt"
```

Then everything works just fine, the **output2.txt** file has only one line with `b` character. So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `/a/d` does not delete a line; it deletes the pattern space.  While a pattern space initially contains just one line, your first substitute command makes the pattern space into two lines.  To remove just the line ending with `a`, try:

```
$ sed "s/a/a\n/ ; s/[^\n]*a\n//" "input.txt"
b
```

The regex `[^\n]*a\n` matches everything on the line that ends with `a`.  It is replaced with nothing.

Alternatively, if you want to delete from the pattern space a line that consists entirely of `a`:

```
$ sed "s/a/\na\n/ ; s/\na\n//" "input.txt"
b
```

#### Documentation

The sed documentation is clear: `d` command deletes the pattern space.

From the [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands):

> d
>  Delete the pattern space; immediately start next cycle.

From the [POSIX awk specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html):

> [2addr]d
>   Delete the pattern space and start the next cycle.

Typically, a sed pattern space consists of a single line in which case the distinction between line and pattern space is unimportant.  But, there are many ways, such as `s/a/a\n/`, of putting multiple lines in a pattern space.  In this case, the difference is important.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the new command, however as I see from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-a-line-containing-a-specific-string-using-sed , the command `/a/d` does actually delete a line containing a specific string. So do you have any idea why my commands won't work as expected?

Comment: @Teiv In that answer the pattern space consisted of a single line.  That is why he wrote that `d` deletes a line.  When the pattern space contains multiple lines, one must be more precise: `d` deletes the pattern space.  Both the GNU documention and the POSIX spec are unambiguous on this: the `d` command deletes the pattern space.  I have updated the answer with links to the documention.